# Want to switch character '\'

Tags: java, character, utf

I want to switch-case the character \ but it is not working as I intend.
Because the character skips over the character after it, what would be the ' of the character literal. So I tried to do it as UTF. But it still does not work. Here is my code:

```
switch(input.charAt(i)){
    case '\u005C':
        actVel ++;
        break;
    case '_':
        if(actVel == 0)
        {
            actVel++;
            plusCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            flat++;
        }
        break;
```

I am getting "Unclosed character literal" as error code.
I would be really grateful for an answer. Thanks :)
 - Cyaena

Comment: `case '\\':` should have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The `\` is a special escape character**.

Here the list of escaped [characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html):

- `\\` for `\`
- `\n` for new line
- `\t` for tab
- `\b` for backspace
- `\r` for carraige return
- `\f` for form feed
- `\'` for the character `'`
- `\"` for the character `"`

For a single `\` you need to use the special sequence `\\`

As an example:

```
System.out.println("Hello boys\\girls!");   // Prints:    Hello boys\girls!
```

Fro your code you need to do the following:

```
case '\\':
    ...
    // Your code here
```

---

From the comment to the answer of aimee.

The string `_/\_` should be written as `"_/\\_"`. The length of this String is 4 and is computed as follow:

```
_   1 character
/   1 character
\\  1 character (printed as \)
_   1 character
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. But the problem is that I read the input string from a .txt file. This .txt is set and I am not allowed to change it.

Comment: In the txt file the content is equal to what is printed. So the text file has content _ / \ _

Answer (score 3):

Try escaping the back-slash by trying `\\`

Comment: That works. But then it creates a new problem. I did not even thought about first. If i want to read in a String like "\__/\\__" this, some characters still get skipped out. How do I change that? I have no way to change the input. It is defenitely set. Even here it escapes the characters...

Comment: Not sure I understood the problem?

Comment: @Cyaena is not possible to write a String "_/ \ _" check my answer for the complete list of escaped characters. This string should be written as "_/\\_"